# Why does stride function work like this in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Below the first code snippet prints 1

```
for i in stride(from: 1, through: 1, by: -1) {
    print(i)
}
```

but why the below snippet prints nothing?

```
for i in stride(from: 1, through: 2, by: -1) {
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a positive stride amount, `stride(from:through:by:)` returns a sequence of all values `x` satisfying

```
start <= x and x <= end
```

which can be reached from the start value by adding the stride zero or more times. For a negative stride, the condition is the other way around:

```
start >= x and x >= end
```

That behavior is symmetric with respect to positive and negative strides:

```
for i in stride(from: 0, through: 0, by: 1) { print(i) } // prints 0
for i in stride(from: 0, through: -1, by: 1) { print(i) } // prints nothing

for i in stride(from: 0, through: 0, by: -1) { print(i) } // prints 0
for i in stride(from: 0, through: 1, by: -1) { print(i) } // prints nothing
```

The implementation can be found in [Stride.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Stride.swift#L525) in the Swift source code repository:

```
  public mutating func next() -> Element? {
    let result = _current.value
    if _stride > 0 ? result >= _end : result <= _end {
      // Note the `>=` and `<=` operators above. When `result == _end`, the
      // following check is needed to prevent advancing `_current` past the
      // representable bounds of the `Strideable` type unnecessarily.
      //
      // If the `Strideable` type is a fixed-width integer, overflowed results
      // are represented using a sentinel value for `_current.index`, `Int.min`.
      if result == _end && !_didReturnEnd && _current.index != .min {
        _didReturnEnd = true
        return result
      }
      return nil
    }
    _current = Element._step(after: _current, from: _start, by: _stride)
    return result
  }
```

Your first example

```
for i in stride(from: 1, through: 1, by: -1) { print(i) }
```

prints `1` because that value satisfies `1 >= 1` and `1 >= 1`. Your second example

```
for i in stride(from: 1, through: 2, by: -1) { print(i) }
```

prints nothing because no value satisfies both conditions `1 >= x` and `x >= 2`.